# Logging in with MVC Identity through a Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Basically, I have 2 sets of projects, 1 contains the Web API Services and the other is the Web Portal which extracts data from the database through the API. However, following the set-up of ASP.Net Identity, the login process is all client-side. Is there any way where I can shift the Identity login to be performed through the API rather than having it directly connecting to my database?

I've tried installing Identity onto the API itself, but I'm also unclear how it is able to authenticate the user even if I pass the data to it.

Comment: What is MVC Identity?  I am only aware of [ASP.Net Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) which is MVC agnostic.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, have corrected it.